# How to find a complexity of a built-in function in python

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I have the special case of the problem, but it would be nice to know whether it is possible for any function.

So I want to find the position of a substring in a string. Ok, in python there is a [find method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) which does exactly what is needed.

> **string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])**
>
> Return the lowest index in s where
>   the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in
>   s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and
>   interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

Amazing, but the problem is that finding a big substring in a big string can run from `O(n*m)` to `O(n)` (which is a huge deal) [depending on the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm). Documentation gives no information about time complexity, nor information about the underlying algorithm.

I see few approaches how to resolve this:

- benchmark
- go to source code and try to understand it

Both does not sound really easy (I hope that there is an easier way). So how can I find a complexity of a built-in function?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [big_o](https://github.com/pberkes/big_O) module.

Comment: @AlexThornton thank you Alex, but this basically falls into my `benchmark` category. Not only it is long to estimate it, it is sometimes really hard to get it (for some probabilistic algorithms or get the edge cases). It just sounds strange that this information is not available in the documentation.

Comment: It is strange. There is a 'TimeComplexity' section on the wiki which tells it to you for a few, but not for methods like `string.find()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say, "go to source code and try to understand it," but it might be easier than you think.  Once you get to the actual implementation code, in [Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9c35973829e6/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h), you find:

```
/* fast search/count implementation, based on a mix between boyer-
   moore and horspool, with a few more bells and whistles on the top.
   for some more background, see: http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm */
```

The [URL referenced there](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm) has a good discussion of the algorithm and its complexity.

Comment: sounds good enough. I am just thinking, what is the point of not including this information in the documentation?

Comment: This would be good information to include in the documentation, you are right.  You could try filing a bug about it at http://bugs.python.org/  One issue is that the stdlib may be implemented differently by different Python implementations, and they may not want to make a promise about complexity for a function like this.